# image of a compactly supported function

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a continuous complex function on a topological space $X$ with compact support $K$.

Then, according to the book "Real and Complex Analysis" by Rudin, it says that:

> If $X$ is not compact, then $0 \in f(X)$, but $0$ need not lie in $f(K)$

But, I cannot come up with an example to see why $0$ need not lie in $f(K)$. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Let $X = [0,1] \cup (2,50)$. Does that give you an idea?

Comment: @DanielFischer Does $[0,1]$ in your example have empty boundary.