# A question about the support of a function in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Here is some excerpts from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*:
[image]
[image]
I have a question about the last statement. It says, "If $K$ is the support of $f \in C_c(X)$, then $f(X) \subset f(K) \cup \{0\} $ ." Because $K$ is the support of $f$, then $f(K)$ contains all non-zero value, why not $f(X) = f(K) \cup \{0\} $ . And why "if $X$ is not compact, then $0 \in f(X)$".

Comment: Also, there's a misprint: it should read $0$ need not lie in $f(\color{red}{X})$.

Comment: @user403337 no, that would be nonsensical since it was stated that $0 \in f(X)$ in the very same sentence. It is correct, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951005/image-of-a-compactly-supported-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f (X)=f(K)\cup \{0\}$ is not correct in general. Take $f(x)=1$ for all $x$.

If $X$ is not compact then $X \neq K$. So there is a point $x \in X\setminus K$. By  definition of support we have $f(x)=0$. Hence $0 \in f(X)$.